# Calculating complex integral using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculate the following complex integral
$$\int_\gamma\frac{(z^2+1)^2}{z^2(2z+3)(3z+2)}dz , $$  $\gamma:|z|=1$

Comment: Which points are enclosed within the given contour? What is the residue of the integrand at those points?

Comment: Use Cauchy Residue Theorem...https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/cauchy.pdf

Comment: i have tried  $f(z)=\frac{(z^2+1)^2}{2z+3}$ and we have $$\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z^2(3z+2)}dz$$
$z=0,\frac{-2}{3}$ in $\gamma$ but i can't partition off simple fraction.

Actually i trying evaluate following integral using Residu Theorem. 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{cos^2x}{13+12cosx}dx$$ So $cosx=\frac{z^2+1}{2z}$ and $dx=\frac{dz}{iz}$ and we have  my first question.